# Imprimir ArrayList, Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtable, arraylist

Estou iniciando os estudos em aplicações Java com Swing, e tenho dúvidas de como imprimir meu ArrayList.

Qual o melhor forma de imprimir ou listar um ArrayList dentro de uma janela?

No meu caso temos uma agenda, inserimos contatos num ArrayList e precisamos listar eles.

Comment: Sem dúvida, atraves do jtable, usando um tablemodel. Veja se [**esse tutorial**](http://www.devmedia.com.br/jtable-utilizando-o-componente-em-interfaces-graficas-swing/28857) te ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Existem várias formas, vai depender do tipo da ArrayList.

Usando JList:

```
List<String> nomes = new ArrayList<String>();
// Parte que preenche a lista com nomes omitida
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
JList list = new JList(model);

for (int i = 0; i < nomes.size(); i++) {
    model.add(i, nomes[i]);
}
```

---

Usando JTable (este exemplo foi tirado de outra fonte):

```
private DefaultTableModel modeloTable;

private void preencherJtableCidade(String query) {
    //Aqui carrego minha lista
    listCidades = cidadeService.searchCiades(query);
    modeloTable = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();

    txtNomeCidadeCadastro.setText("");
    cidadeModel.setCidadeID(0);
    cidadeModel.setNomeCidade("");
    cidadeModel.setEstado(null);
    cidadeModel.setPais(null);

    //Aqui verifico se a jTable tem algum registo se tiver eu deleto
    while (modeloTable.getRowCount() > 0) {
        modeloTable.removeRow(0);
    }

             //Aqui eu adiciono cada linha da lista na jTable
    for (CidadeModel c : listCidades) {
        modeloTable.addRow(new Object[] { c.getCidadeID(),
                c.getNomeCidade(), c.getEstado().getEstadoID(), c.getEstado().getNomeEstado(),
                c.getPais().getPaisID(),c.getPais().getNomePais() });
    }
}
```

Fonte:
http://www.guj.com.br/9696-como-popular-uma-jtable-com-um-array-list-de-objetos